# How to wait till file is getting downloaded or available in required folder?

Tags: java, selenium, testng

On clicking the download button a file will be downloaded in my project `dir` and I want to read that file content this is `pdf`

File name is dynamic. It starts with same name but in middle the content is dynamic and ends with `.pdf` extension.

**Code**:

```
   public static String isFileDownloaded(String fileText, String fileExtension, int timeOut) {
String folderName = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\test\\resources\\Download\\";
File[] listOfFiles;
int waitTillSeconds = timeOut;
boolean fileDownloaded = false;
String filePath = null; 

long waitTillTime = Instant.now().getEpochSecond() + waitTillSeconds;
while (Instant.now().getEpochSecond() < waitTillTime) {
    listOfFiles = new File(folderName).listFiles();
    for (File file : listOfFiles) {
        String fileName = file.getName().toLowerCase();
        if (fileName.contains(fileText.toLowerCase()) && fileName.contains(fileExtension.toLowerCase())) {
            fileDownloaded = true;
            filePath = fileName.getAbsolutePath();
            break;
        }
    }
    if (fileDownloaded) {
        break;
    }
}
return filePath;
```

}

```
public static  String readPdfContent(String fileName) throws IOException {
    
    File file = new File(System.getProperty(fileName));
    PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(file);
    int numberOfPages = getPageCount(doc);
    System.out.println("The total number of pages "+numberOfPages);
    String content = new PDFTextStripper().getText(doc);
    doc.close();    
return content;
```

}

```
try {
        JSclick(download);
        String filePath = isFileDownloaded("Personal Data", ".pdf", 30);
        if(filePath != null){
        String pdfContent = readPdfContent(filePath);
        Assert.assertTrue(pdfContent.contains("Test Kumar"));
        Assert.assertTrue(pdfContent.contains("XXXXX"));
        }else {
             System.out.println("Some issue with file downloading");
        }
       
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

[image: file]

it show me error-:The method getAbsolutePath() is undefined for the type String
Can you please help on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Create a method to check whether a file is fully downloaded or not.
- Call that method wherever it's required.

**Method to check file is downloaded or not**: This method is to search for specific file with partial or full text in download folder for given time and returns the absolute path of the file.

> ```
> @param fileText - Partial or full file name
> @param fileExtension - .pdf, .txt
> @param timeOut - How many seconds you are expecting for file to be downloaded.
> ```

```
    public static String isFileDownloaded(String fileText, String fileExtension, int timeOut) {
        String folderName = "location of download folde";
        File[] listOfFiles;
        int waitTillSeconds = timeOut;
        boolean fileDownloaded = false;
        String filePath = null; 

        long waitTillTime = Instant.now().getEpochSecond() + waitTillSeconds;
        while (Instant.now().getEpochSecond() < waitTillTime) {
            listOfFiles = new File(folderName).listFiles();
            for (File file : listOfFiles) {
                String fileName = file.getName().toLowerCase();
                if (fileName.contains(fileText.toLowerCase()) && fileName.contains(fileExtension.toLowerCase())) {
                    fileDownloaded = true;
                    filePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (fileDownloaded) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return filePath;
    }
```

**Call the `isFileDownloaded` method**:

As you know the partial file name then you can pass the input like below to get the file path.

```
String filePath = isFileDownloaded("Personal Data", ".pdf", 30);
System.out.println("Complete path of file:"+ filePath);
```

**Output**:

```
C:\Users\Download\Personal data...pdf
```

**Updated code for OP's logic**:

**Try block**:

```
    try {
        JSclick(download);
        String filePath = isFileDownloaded("Personal Data", ".pdf", 30);
        if(filePath != null){
        String pdfContent = readPdfContent(filePath);
        Assert.assertTrue(pdfContent.contains("Test Kumar"));
        Assert.assertTrue(pdfContent.contains("XXXXX"));
        }
       }else{
         System.out.println("Some issue with file downloading");
       }
```

**Read pdf content method**:

```
public static  String readPdfContent(String fileName) throws IOException {
        
        File file = new File(System.getProperty(fileName);    
        PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(file);
        int numberOfPages = getPageCount(doc);
        System.out.println("The total number of pages "+numberOfPages);
        String content = new PDFTextStripper().getText(doc);
        doc.close();
    return content;
}
```

Comment: First i have clean that directory then download the file it is downloaded but i want to get file name to read a content in it. how can i get file name can you please tell me.

Comment: \src\test\resources\Download\Download (The system cannot find the file specified) i don't know why i get file name is Download this is beacuse i can't read that content.

Comment: My answer deals with waiting for a file to be downloaded based on given file name and extension. If you know the file name then you need to pass it to the method. From where you will get the file name? or do you read the file name from some place?

Comment: @ankushsingh updated the answer please try and let me know.

Comment: You're not incrementing `passedTimeInSeconds`, thus the loop will be infinite. If the file doesn't ever appear, the method returns `null` - which may cause issues on concatenating with a string. If the user doesn't have permissions on the folder, `File(folderName).listFiles()` will throw an exception - that needs to be handled. And the last thing - it'll return on partial file download, not only on complete (hint: because of the way you check the extension; Chrome usually puts ".part" at the end, for example).

Comment: @TodorMinakov Thank you for your inputs I missed to increase the time I will update that. And other points whatever you said those are also correct but as per OP's question I just wrote the answer. Thanks again for reviewing :)

Comment: i have increase time File to be downloaded successfully But again the errror is :-src\test\resources\Download\Download (The system cannot find the file specified)  why i get filename is Download name instead of Personal Data-format0afb8c503e654dc89157111b1726ddc2_96596.pdf

Comment: Can you update the question with latest code what you are trying?

Comment: i have updated please see this..

Comment: You haven't implemented the code what I posted. Any issue?

Comment: yes in this filePath = fileName.getAbsolutePath();  in getAbsolutePath() shows error:-The method getAbsolutePath() is undefined for the type String..

Comment: Updated the code for your logic. Please check.

Comment: i have updated your logic in my code but in  filePath = fileName.getAbsolutePath(); it throws me error:-The method getAbsolutePath() is undefined for the type String.

Comment: Please try `filePath = file.getAbsolutePath();`

Comment: Is that working now?

Comment: yes it is working somehow but another error is coming:-src\test\resources\Download\Personal Data-format0afb8c503e654dc89157111b1726ddc2_98276.pdf.crdownload (The system cannot find the file specified). In this last name of file extention .crdownload is coming thats why it is not read that properly

Comment: Thanks for give good suggestion its working..

Answer (score 0):

Well you can simply list all files in folder and take the newest

Like something:

```
File f = new File("download_folder");
String[] pathnames = f.list();
```

then you can use for-loop to find what you need

Comment: First i have clean that directory then download the file. It is downloaded but i want to get file name to read a content in it. how can i get file name can you please tell me.  the error is coming:- \src\test\resources\Download\Download (The system cannot find the file specified) i don't know why i get file name is Download this is beacuse i can't read that content.

Comment: Maybe you try to access it before download is finished?

Comment: so should i use wait for a second ?

Comment: yes, 1 or 5 and try again. You can just debug and pause on breakpoint and manually check if file is downloaded correctly. Then run your code further.